# Booting problem? Need to fsck every time in order to make everything work!

Tags: boot, fsck, inode

I own an old laptop (model emachines e525) with 4GB of RAM and I installed Ubuntu 16.04.
Everything was fine during and after the installation. I updated it and installed just a few apps (vlc, smplayer, clementine..)

After few days, Clementine stopped working - just like that! I noticed that SMPlayer also won't run, but VLC was fine. ALso, terminal stopped working and some other apps like rhythmbox. I wanted to reboot but it stopped at the point where the screen is purple. With no other option, I forced the shut down and then turn it on again.

Soooooo that was the first time I had to RUN FSCK MANUALY for SDA1.
Everything worked after that. The problem is that everytime I turn on the computer the SAME DARN THING happens - few (or most apps) won't run, sometimes it fails to mount external disks, then I HAVE TO force shut it down, run fsck manualy and only then everything works!

Also, while fsck-ing, it says that there are orphane inodes that need to be fixed or removed or relocated or something else...

Does anybody have any idea what is causing this problem? How do I fix this permanently?

I already tried re-installing Ubuntu twice but with no success..

Comment: may be check the RAM with memtest ?

Comment: Also, run Gnome Disk Utility and check the health status of the drive.  From the Ubuntu Dash find -> **Disk** -> (From the Utility Click the top right **Menu Icon**) -> (click) **Smart Data & Self Tests**.  This should indicate if the drive is going bad.  Look for errors in the **Assessment** column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!It says disk is ok and has 376 bad sectors. I ran another self test (short) and the test failed (wasn't doing anything other than that while testing). What does this mean?

Comment: That many bad sectors and a failed short self test are strong indicators that the drive is on its last legs.  Even in a laptop, it's a minor job to replace a hard disk, and it's time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was afraid that would happen soon :/

Answer (score 0):

If runing `fsck` solve your problem , you can change the frequency of the automatic check , you can perform the automatic file system check through `fsck` on every boot:

```
 sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sdXY
```

Change `sdXY` with your root partition

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed it like you suggested, now we will see how it goes :)

Comment: Nope, nothing changed, still needed to force shut down and manually fsck..

Comment: @GordanaMarcetic try this answer on U&L : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123964/153195

Answer (score 0):

Next thing I'd do is try to run a S.M.A.R.T. check on the laptop's hard disk.  The recurring need to `fsck` manually, with the same or similar symptoms, suggests the hard disk media or read-write circuitry may be failing.  Assumigng that's the case, a new hard disk (should be cheap for a computer that age) is likely to fix you right up.

Comment: Yes, I thought this might be the case because it's rather old.. The self test said it's ok (see my comment above) but I'm not so sure..